# How to properly implement callback logic with reading stream in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, httprequest, pug

I am trying to implement small RSS reader (that would present feed data as html pages) in node.js.

I have so far came to this point:

```
var FeedParser = require(__dirname + '/../node_modules/feedparser')
  , request = require(__dirname + '/../node_modules/request');

exports.news = function(req, res){

  var news = []; 
    request('http://feeds.feedburner.com/niebezpiecznik/')
    .pipe(new FeedParser())
      .on('error', function(error) {
        // ...
      })  
      .on('meta', function (meta) {
        console.log('===== %s =====', meta.title);
        console.log('**** %s ****', meta.description);
        console.log();
      })  
      .on('readable', function() {
        var stream = this, item;
        var i = 0;
        while (item = stream.read()) {

          var this_news = { 
            'title': item.title,
            'description': item.description
          }   
          news.push(this_news);
          console.log(i++);
        }   
        res.render('rss', {
          title: 'Node.js based RSS reader',
          newsi: JSON.stringify(news)
        }); 
    }); 

};
```

with following jade template :

extends layout

```
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  script(type='text/javascript').
    var inews = JSON.parse('!{newsi}');
    console.log(inews);
  ul  
  for news in newsi
    li= news
  else
    li sorry, no newsHERE!
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
0
GET /rss 304 532ms
0
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:691:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/home/XXX/programming/nodejs/node-express-aws/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:63:22)
    at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (/home/XXX/programming/nodejs/node-express-aws/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:527:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.contentType.res.type (/home/XXX/programming/nodejs/node-express-aws/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:396:15)
    at ServerResponse.res.send (/home/XXX/programming/nodejs/node-express-aws/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:112:14)
    at fn (/home/XXX/programming/nodejs/node-express-aws/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/XXX/programming/nodejs/node-express-aws/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:222:12)
    at View.render (/home/XXX/programming/nodejs/node-express-aws/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (/home/XXX/programming/nodejs/node-express-aws/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:504:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/XXX/programming/nodejs/node-express-aws/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:798:7)
```

Where should I put this `render` part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readable` event may be triggered multiple times, even when you call `read` from within its handler I think.

I'm not familiar with the Feedparser module, but try using the `data` and `end` events:

```
.on('data', function(item) {
  var this_news = { 
    'title': item.title,
    'description': item.description
  }   
  news.push(this_news);
  console.log(i++);
})
.on('end', function() {
  res.render('rss', {
    title: 'Node.js based RSS reader',
    newsi: JSON.stringify(news)
  }); 
});
```

If that doesn't work, you can still use your `readable` event handler but make sure to call `res.render` from the `end` handler.

Comment: I wouldn't use the `data` event because it turns the stream into the old stream interface. He just needs to add the `end` event like you've done.